# Where to put "stop" to end the simulation

Tags: netlogo

I want to stop my simulation if there is no certain patch (target) to occupy. I did the following code but still not working. It just stopped the turtle, not the simulation. I did this "target" variable as globals and to include it in "go" but also cannot stop the simulation.

```
to set-move
 ask migrants
  [set pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
   set target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
   ifelse (count target != 0 and (status != "resident")) [move-to min-one-of target [value]
                                                          set status "resident"
                                                          set color blue]
                                                    [stop]
  ]
```

Here is the full code

```
breed [migrants migrant]
breed [residents resident]

patches-own [value]
turtles-own [income
status]

to setup
  ca
  let total problo + probmid + probhi
  if (total != 100)
     [print (word "prob is more than 100")]
  ask patches [set value random-normal 10 3
  let patch-value value
    set pcolor scale-color (gray - 5) patch-value 10 3]
  ask patches
  [if random 100 < 3
    [sprout-residents 1
      [set color red
       set shape "default"
       set size 1
       set status "resident"
      ]
    ]
  ]

end

to go

  ask patches
  [if not any? patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here] [stop ]
    if random 100 < 1
    [sprout-migrants 1
      [set color green
       set shape "default"
       set size 1
       set status "migrant"
       set-move

  ]]]

end


to set-move
  let pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
  let target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
  if any? target and (status != "resident")
  [ move-to min-one-of target [value]
    set status "resident"
    set color blue
  ]
end
```

[image]

Comment: Please clarify what you are trying to stop - the simulation, or just the process of creating more turtles

Comment: I want to stop the simulation which also (I think) will stop creating more turtles. So when there are no more patches to occupy, the simulation will stop and no more turtles are sprouted.

Comment: At the moment, multiple turtles are created during each tick. At the beginning of the tick, the go procedure checks if there are any available patches and stops the simulation if there are not. However, imagine there are 3 patches available, it doesn't stop, but your create procedure may sprout 5 turtles, and there's nowhere for the last two to go. So you need to add a check so that a turtle is sprouted only if there's a spot for it. That's different from stopping the simulation.

Comment: Just as a general comment, why are they moving at all? Is the movement meaningful in some way? If you just want turtles to be on certain patches, then you can sprout them in those places rather than move them.

Comment: I think you are right about the movement. There is no certain meaning for that. I will consider to sprout it directly from the target patch.

Comment: Netlogo runs the program such as in go procedure is line by line right? So when the if condition is not met then it will stop and it will not run the next command right? Am I wrong in understanding this?

Comment: You are correct that it runs line by line but you have misunderstood what `stop` actually does. It ends the code block, not the simulation, and then jumps 'out' a level. So the only way to use it to stop the simulation is to have it at the top level inside the go procedure. Then it will break the go procedure, which you have probably called with a forever button.

Comment: On the question of sprouting - is something supposed to happen after all these turtles have been created, do they interact in some way and do something? If so, this turtle generation should all be part of the setup procedure not the actual simulation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The primitive `stop` will terminate the code block within which the `stop` appears. In your code, once the condition is met, the set-move procedure will end, but that doesn't end the simulation. What you need to do is test for the condition at the top level (the go procedure) and that will terminate the run. I'm a little confused by your code, but I think the answer is to separate the moving part from the checking whether to stop.

So, in set-move change:

```
ifelse (count target != 0 and (status != "resident"))
[ move-to min-one-of target [value]
  set status "resident"
  set color blue
]
[ stop ]
```

simply to an `if` block instead of `ifelse` (removing the `stop` as well). Then, at the top level, add a line something like:

```
if not any? patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here] [stop]
```

I'm also concerned by your code structure of set-move starting with `ask migrants`. I suspect that this is an error. What you are saying is, any time set-move gets called, ALL the migrants try and move. I think you intended that only the newly created migrant tries to move since you called this from within the `sprout` code block. If so, then your set-move is a turtle procedure and should look like:

```
to set-move
  set pot-target patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here]
  set target pot-target with [count neighbors with [any? turtles-here with [value < 11]] >= 1]
  if any? target and (status != "resident")
  [ move-to min-one-of target [value]
    set status "resident"
    set color blue
  ]
end
```

Note that I also changed your `count != 0` to `not any?` as a readability suggestion. Personally, I would also name the agentset targets rather than target to remind yourself that it may have multiple members.

UPDATE: You need to have your `stop` at the top level of the go procedure so that it stops that procedure. It should look something like this:

```
to go
 if not any? patches with [value < 11 and not any? turtles-here] [stop ]
 ask patches
 [ if random 100 < 1
   [ sprout-migrants 1
     [ set color green
```

Comment: Thank you Jumboman, I think it is better to use stop than to replace it with loop.

Comment: Thank you JenB. I follow your suggestion and I think it is working well. Like you said, I think the main problem is in ask migrants. So now in set-move I erase the ask migrants and put in ask patches of go the stop command.

Comment: I repost the full code as shown above. I think that is already working well.

Comment: see my update, you don't have it in quite the right place

Comment: Sometimes it is not working. The patches keep sprouting the turtles. When it is working, there are two (or more) turtles on a patch. So, I tried to put it in ask patches command so that patches stop sprouting the turtles. When it worked, there was only a turtle on a patch which is good. But when it did not work, the result is same as putting the command at the top level.

Comment: Sorry, I just did it.

Answer (score -2):

rather than using [stop] to end a simulation, I would propose you use while loop instead.

```
while [not stop-condition][
  run
]
```

Comment: The problem with this approach is that it conflicts with the `tick` time progression structure of NetLogo programs. Can you please explain why you think this is a better approach than using `stop`, which is what is recommended in NetLogo documentation?

Comment: clarity. If you have a large code base and others will look at your code, `[stop]` is easy to overlook and comes pretty out of the blue. a while-loop, especially in the form of `while [running condition]`, will immediatly make it clear that this code is supposed to keep running until some condition is met, and will prone you to look for that condition.